# uiautomator feature not consistent with all ROM

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am writing an simple UI test app by following  [uiautomator guildline](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html). 
Mentioned sample worked on S5, but also fail on some of occasion. **Not sure why?**

**Another issue:** But same thing not working on another mob Sony-Z I have tested.

Following error log:

> **com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException:
>   UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=Apps]  at**
>   com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(UiObject.java:432)
>     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(UiObject.java:410)
>     at
>   com.org.example.test.LaunchSettings.testDemo(LaunchSettings.java:26)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:160)
>     at
>   com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:96)
>     at
>   com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:91)
>     at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any suggestion here.

Comment: Do the 2 devices have the same dpi ? If not, visible objects can be differents from a device to another. So it can explain the UiObjectNotFoundException

Comment: but then to rely on test case execution for different-2 device!

Comment: For me the purpose of UI testing is to see if the app is working on different devices with different config (such as screen size, orientation, ...). Maybe your test failed because there is a problem in your app. Can you provide a sample code of your app and test ? Another question, is this error raised every time in the Sony-Z ?

Comment: Hi..I am also running for same purpose. And I am using exactly same sample given on Android Developer site for same Default 'Settings'application.

Comment: ok, be sure you have the right tools 
`To use these tools, you must have the following versions of the Android development tools installed:
Android SDK Tools, Revision 21 or higher
Android SDK Platform, API 16 or higher`

You can also move to [UiAutomator 2.0](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html)

Comment: I am using with required setup you mentioned here. So is it confimed it might by bug. Did you also expereince it before. And Thanks for 2.0 update ..I will check it.